# How to upload image on mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a shopping website using php and mysql. I upload and save an image to mysql database. When i run this code the image does not display on index.php page.

[image]

here is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <?php
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            include("navbar.php");
        } else {
            include("index_navbar.php");
        }
    
    ?>


    

    <!-- heading start here -->
    <div class="card shadow bg-success">
        <div class="card-body">

            <center>
                <b>
                    <h1 class="card-title text-dark mt-4 mb-4">plant booking</h1>

                </b>

                <h3 class="card-title text-white mt-4 mb-4">Save Plant, Save Earth...</h3>

            </center>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- heading end here -->


    <br>



    <?php
    include("connection.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM addplant";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    ?>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <?php

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card border-secondary shadow my-2 " style="width: 17rem; height: 25rem">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <center>
                                <img style="width:230px; height:180px" class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
                            </center>

                            <br>
                            <p class="card-text text-left"><b>Name : </b><br><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
                            <p class="card-text text-left"><b>Scientific Name : </b><br><?php echo $row['sci']; ?></p>

                            <center>
                                <a href="booking.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-secondary">Book</a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php 
            }?>

        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- cart ends here -->

    <!-- footer background image -->
    <img style="width: 1350px;" src="img/index.jpg">
    <!-- footer background image -->





</body>

</html>
```

The process is, first admin add plant then that plant show on index page .
here is addplant.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
include("navbar.php");


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card border-success container shadow mt-5 mb-5">

                <!-- image start here -->
                <center>
                    <img src="img/addplant.jpg" style="width: 360px;">
                </center>
                <!-- image end here -->

                <center>
                    <h1 class="mb-5"><b>Plant Information</b></h1>
                </center>
                
                <form action="process/process_addplant.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name Of Plant</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter plant name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Scientific Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sci" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter scientific name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Required Soil</label>
                        <input type="text" name="soil" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter soil variety">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Required Water</label>
                        <input type="text" name="water" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter water in liter">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Required Climate</label>
                        <input type="text" name="climate" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter climate">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Required fertilizer</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fertilizer" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter fertilizers">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Max Height</label>
                        <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter height in meter">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Famous For</label>
                        <input type="text" name="famous" class="form-control" required="true" placeholder="enter here">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Picture</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control" required="true">
                    </div>


                    <center>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">ADD</button>
                        </div>
                    </center>

                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

here is process_addplant.php. This page contains upload image code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>


    <?php

    include('../connection.php');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $sci = $_POST['sci'];
    $soil = $_POST['soil'];
    $water = $_POST['water'];
    $climate = $_POST['climate'];
    $fertilizer = $_POST['fertilizer'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $famous = $_POST['famous'];
    $files = $_FILES['file'];

    $filename = $files['name'];
    $fileerror = $files['error'];
    $filetmp = $files['tmp_name'];

    $fileext = explode('.', $filename);
    $filecheck = strtolower(end($fileext));

    $fileextstored = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');

    if (in_array($filecheck, $fileextstored)) {

        $destinationfile = 'upload/' . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $destinationfile);

        // $query1 = "INSERT INTO addplant(image) VALUES ('$destinationfile')";
        // $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);


    }



    $query = "INSERT INTO addplant(name,sci,soil,water,climate,fertilizer,height,famous,image) VALUES ('$name','$sci','$soil','$water','$climate','$fertilizer','$height','$famous','$destinationfile')";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    if ($sql) {

        echo '<center><div class="bg-success text-white">';
        echo "<h3>Plant Added Successfully...</h3>";
        echo '</div></center>';
        header("Refresh:1; ../index.php");
    } else {

        echo '<center><div class="bg-dark text-white">';
        echo "<h3>Plant Not Added...</h3>";
        echo '</div></center>';
        header("Refresh:1; ../addplant.php");
    }

    ?>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the file saved in the server? Is the path saved correctly in the database? Is the path correct relative to the display page? So much information is missing... remember we cannot run your code or see your environment. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: 1) Check the file upload location to see if file was actually uploaded   2) If it was, check the database to make sure the correct path is displayed.  Remember that when loading the file, the path must be relative to the page you are opening unless you are storing it as an absolute url.  3) Go into browser on page and view source code.  Check to see if the code is generating the correct ABSOLUTE location to the upload directory.  LEt me know answers to above and I may be able to diagnose further

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Also none of your code actually checks whether the file was successfully uploaded, or saved. You retrieve `$fileerror` but then never actually use it to check the status. You also try to check the extension of the filename, but then ignore the result of that when saving to the database.

Comment: hi i want to add image DYNAMICALLY from the mysql database, did you have proper code to access image from mysql database

Comment: We understand your requirements, and your basic approach of trying to load the image is ok...so if it's not showing the image you need to debug the code and find out why. We can't run your code, so you need to answer the questions we're asking, and then we can help to diagnose the root cause of your issue - probably in the upload process or the URL structure. It's not a case of giving you a general example, this stuff relies on specifics. P.s. You can fix the SQL injection problems by following the links I provided and applying the examples (there and on many other sites) to your situation.

Comment: The other things I pointed out will help with your debugging - e.g. checking the value of $fileerror would help you determine if the upload had a problem. Not inserting the record if the extension isn't acceptable will stop you ending up with a link to a file which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add **/** at starting position of image source
Example :-

```
<img src="/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
```

Comment: That's based on an assumption that you can't prove. Instead of guessing, wait for the OP the clarify the exact issue.

Comment: it's not assumption he has uploaded files to upload folder and not added / and after adding it will work fine.

Comment: You're assuming things about the folder structure and the position of the files within it, and the configuration of the webserver. You're also assuming that the URL is even the issue... We don't actually know if the file was uploaded or the query succeeded. So yes your answer is nothing but speculation.